# Joomla Server Migration Tool, Script, or Assistant

Tags: joomla, webserver

What Tool, Script, or Assistant provides the easiest way to perform server migration on a Joomla 1.6 website ?

I was thinking that I would do the following:

- Backup Existing Files using FileZilla
- Perform a DB Backup using LazyBackup
- Upload site to new server using FileZilla
- Migrate DB using phpMyAdmin
- Update configuration.php w/ new references
- Update folder permissions for cache, tmp, log, images directories

What extra steps should be done to ensure SEO won't be hurt after a server migration?

Answer (score 1):

All steps can be performed using [Akeeba Kickstart](https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/akeeba-kickstart-documentation.html)
after creating a backup with the help of [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/akeeba-backup-documentation.html)

Comment: thanks for the response. Can you list the steps required ?